# Is trip purpose a case-specific variable in a multinomial logit for transport?

Tags: logistic, multinomial-logit, transportation

I'm trying to run a logit model for transport mode choice between 3 modes. Like every other transport choice models I have case specific variables like income of the passenger and alternative specific variables like travel time. For each respondent I present 6 choice sets. I've got 2 variables namely trip purpose(leisure, business) and partysize(alone and with group). How should I enter these variables to the model. Can these variables be treated as case-specific in multinomial logit?
Thank you